# UnparsedFlagAccessError: Trying to access flag --preserve_unused_tokens before flags were parsed

Tags: python, tokenize, bert-language-model

Hello I am a beginner in ML. I tried to use BERT and tokenizer didn't work like below.

```
train_input = bert_encode(train.text.values, tokenizer, max_len=160)
test_input = bert_encode(test.text.values, tokenizer, max_len=160)
train_labels = train.target.values

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/flags/_flagvalues.py in __getattr__(self, name)
     496         # get too much noise.
     497         logging.error(error_message)
 --> 498       raise _exceptions.UnparsedFlagAccessError(error_message)
     499 
     500   def __setattr__(self, name, value):

     UnparsedFlagAccessError: Trying to access flag --preserve_unused_tokens before flags were parsed.
```

Comment: Please read the guide on how to ask a question:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you solve it, it is my problem also